# can I pass data when routing in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass a lot of data (`json`) when routing to a new controller in angular.
In controller A I call `$location.path('/B');` which in turn will route to controller B.
I know I can pass parameter in the url itself, but I have a lot of data.
Can angular do something similar to 'POST' method and pass data in this way?

Comment: Why not have controller B load the data? You could also use a service to maintain state between controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to bother with POST like behavior with angular.

You have several ways to do this :

- use a service that will preserve data across page loads
- pass real GET argument (when the page is specifically linked to this argument, for example an object ID used to display this object details)
- store data in local storage / session storage
- use controller 'resolve' functionnality to fetch new data before displaying page (not what you want to do though...)

Answer (score 1):

Remember you're not actually changing the page, so you don't need to 'POST' data anywhere or do anything similar.

Instead you should create a service that makes that data available through dependency injection, then specify the dependency when you instantiate the controller that handles the new route.

Comment: Service feels to me like preserving a state. I would like something like passing parameteres to method. For example, If I refresh the page I am relying on the service state which might be different.

Comment: Put some context around your question and I will try to help to give a better answer.